# Unir select para totalizar resultados

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Tabela desejada com o Select]
Como totalizar a quantidade armazenada desses produtos para poder comparar com a quantidade total do pedido para revenda "QTD PEDIDO".Como posso fazer para encontrar o total armazenado e unir ao resultado?

## Select:

```
  SELECT ipv.ProdCodEstr 'CÓDIGO DO PRODUTO',
                       p.ProdNome AS 'NOME PRODUTO',
                       SUM (CAST(ipv.ItPedVendaQtd AS REAL)) AS 'QTD PEDIDO',
                           'total por produto' AS 'local 1',
                           'total por produto' AS 'local 2',
                           'total por produto' AS 'local 3'
FROM PED_VENDA pv WITH (nolock), STAT_PED_VENDA spv WITH (nolock), ITEM_PED_VENDA ipv WITH (nolock)
LEFT JOIN ESTQ_LOC_ARMAZ EstLoc WITH (nolock) ON (EstLoc.ProdCodEstr = ipv.ProdCodEstr)
LEFT JOIN PRODUTO p on(p.ProdCodEstr = ipv.ProdCodEstr)
WHERE ipv.PedVendaNum = pv.PedVendaNum
  AND p.ProdCodEstr = ipv.ProdCodEstr
  AND ipv.ItPedVendaServ LIKE 'Não'
  AND spv.StatPedVendaCod NOT IN ('08',
                                  '10',
                                  '11',
                                  '12',
                                  '13',
                                  '14',
                                  '15',
                                  '16')
  AND pv.PedVendaData BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND -- Data iinicial
 '2017-12-01' -- Data final

GROUP BY ipv.ProdCodEstr,
         p.ProdNome
```

Comment: SUM( local 1 + local 2 + local 3 )

Comment: @AndreTovar: Em qual coluna está a informação de local?

Comment: @AndreTovar: A tabela STAT_PED_VENDA se relaciona com qual tabela e através de qual coluna? //  Sugestão: na cláusula FROM, não misture sintaxe antiga com sintaxe nova.

Comment: A coluna ( EstqLocArmazQtd ) com as quantidades armazenadas está na tabela ESTQ_LOC_ARMAZ que apresenta as seguintes chaves primárias  : EmpCod e ProdCodEstr. Eu não sei como relacionar a tabela (ESTQ_LOC_ARMAZ) com o select que fiz totalizando a quantidade de produtos no pedido de venda. @JoséDiz

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta de regra geral:

Você pode transforma o resultado de qualquer select em uma "tabela virtual" e fazer uma operação nela. Não esqueça do T1 lá embaixo.

No seu caso:

```
select sum('QTD PEDIDO')
from
(
 SELECT ipv.ProdCodEstr 'CÓDIGO DO PRODUTO',
                       p.ProdNome AS 'NOME PRODUTO',
                       SUM (CAST(ipv.ItPedVendaQtd AS REAL)) AS 'QTD PEDIDO',
                           'total por produto' AS 'local 1',
                           'total por produto' AS 'local 2',
                           'total por produto' AS 'local 3'
FROM PED_VENDA pv WITH (nolock), STAT_PED_VENDA spv WITH (nolock), ITEM_PED_VENDA ipv WITH (nolock)
LEFT JOIN ESTQ_LOC_ARMAZ EstLoc WITH (nolock) ON (EstLoc.ProdCodEstr = ipv.ProdCodEstr)
LEFT JOIN PRODUTO p on(p.ProdCodEstr = ipv.ProdCodEstr)
WHERE ipv.PedVendaNum = pv.PedVendaNum
  AND p.ProdCodEstr = ipv.ProdCodEstr
  AND ipv.ItPedVendaServ LIKE 'Não'
  AND spv.StatPedVendaCod NOT IN ('08',
                                  '10',
                                  '11',
                                  '12',
                                  '13',
                                  '14',
                                  '15',
                                  '16')
  AND pv.PedVendaData BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND -- Data iinicial
 '2017-12-01' -- Data final

GROUP BY ipv.ProdCodEstr,
         p.ProdNome
) 
As T1
```